# Reading a matrix of characters from file

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to read a matrix of characters from a file in order to solve a more complicated problem but I don't know where the reading goes wrong.I've attached pics of the o/p of my following code and the actual problem. Please give me a hint, I don't necessarily expect a full solution.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *f;

void matrix()
{
    int i,j,nl,nc;
    char c;

    char file[50][50];

    fscanf(f,"%d %d \n",&nl,&nc);

    for(i=0;i<nl;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<nc;j++)
        {
            c = getc(f) ;
            file[i][j]=c;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<nl;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<nc;j++)
        printf("%c",file[i][j]);
        printf(" \n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int set;
    f=fopen("in.txt","r");

    fscanf(f,"%d \n",&set);

    while(set!=0)
    {
        matrix();

        set--;
    }
}
```

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '{',  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling C library functions (like `fopen()` and `fscanf()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: `getc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`

Comment: regarding: `for(j=0;j<nc;j++)
            printf("%c",file[i][j]);printf(" \n");`  the second call to `printf()` will not be executed as part of the `for()` code block.  Strongly suggest always incorporating the braces '{' '}' around code blocks

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Names like `nl` and `nc` are meaningless, even in the current context.   Suggest, for readability and understanding, names like: `numRows` and `numCols`

Comment: regarding: `c = getc(f) ;
            file[i][j] = c;`  between these two statements, strongly suggest checking for the newline '\n' and if found, perform another call to `getc()`

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  The compiler will output several warning messages that need to be fixed.  Note: other compilers use different options to check the same conditions.

Comment: regarding: `void matrix()`  since this is using an implicit prototype, the compiler will produce code that allows for any number of parameters.  Suggest using: `void matrix( void )`

Comment: the posted code fails to calculate the number of islands and fails to write an appropriate line (for each test case) into the output file: `countedIslands.txt` the number of islands found

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you're not reading the newline character. After each row, read one character (you may report an error if it's not a newline `\n`).